# Position:absolute and overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, position, overflow, css-position, hidden

I am trying to have some images inside a div. Only one image should be shown. I use:

```
<div id="slideshow" style="width:600px;height:400px;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;"></div>
<img src="img3.png" width="600px" height="400px" id="img3" style="position:absolute;left:0px;">
<img src="img2.png" width="600px" height="400px" id="img2" style="position:absolute;left:600px;">
<img src="img1.png" width="600px" height="400px" id="img1"     style="position:absolute;left:1200px;">
</div>
```

But the images overflow from the div and are visible. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not that I know the reasons for your choice in css, but why don't you just float those images instead of making them absolutely positioned?

Comment: How would I do this? (Sorry, I'm a complete beginner in css)

Comment: <img src="img3.png" id="img3" style="width:600px; height:400px; float:left;"> your inline width and height declarations not only had invalid values, but are discouraged. Use CSS when available always. And try to avoid inline like this. A stylesheet definition would be much better. Perhaps I should convert this to an answer...

Comment: Probably should. Works great.

Comment: I posted as an answer then by some magic on SO it seemed to post twice. Hopefully I only deleted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by fixing your markup...

```
<style>
#slideshow{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#slideshow img{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}
</style>

<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="img3.png" id="img3">
    <img src="img2.png" id="img2">
    <img src="img1.png" id="img1">
</div>
```

So the reason why is because you defined position:absolute in both the parent and the children. You could have wrapped the image tags in a relatively positioned div. That would reset the absolute position to the top left of the relative positioned parent.

However, in this case, all you needed to do was float left. There was no reason to have absolute positioned children in the slideshow element.